# Html scrolling text

Tags: html

I now there is a way to create scrolling text into a html page(Like the stockmarket pages), without the need of javascript or similar, but i forgot how the name of the tag that did that.

Can someone help me to remember?

Comment: What do you mean with "scrolling text"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean the HTML `<marquee>` tag?

I wouldn't use it though. It is deprecated by the W3C and not advised by them for use.

Read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element).

Alternatives could be CSS3 animation or CSS3 marquee, but this isn't supported in all browsers.

Read [here](http://cssplay.co.uk/menu/css3-marquee.html) or [here](http://ajnaware.wordpress.com/2008/08/14/scrolling-text-with-webkit-marquee/)

Comment: What should i use instead of that?

Answer (score 2):

See CSS overflow, overflow-x, overflow-y properties (values scroll or auto).

-edit-: Okay, misunderstood the question. Agreed with `<marquee>`.

Answer (score 2):

```
   <marquee> tag, </marquee>
```

Though it is non standard tag, it is supported by all major browser

Answer (score 1):

It is the [MARQUEE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element) tag.

But do not use it as it is considered *Evil*.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's the marquee tag.  [Example guide on use here](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/_MARQUEE.html)

Answer (score 1):

I found what you looking for at this site:
http://www.computerhope.com/top10.htm

It is a tag called `<marquee>`

Answer (score 1):

Though your question is vague I'm going to gues your in need of this

```
<marquee>Text here</marquee>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`<MARQUEE>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element), but it's deprecated.

It's not advised by W3C because moving text in general is distracting.