# How to make marquee stop on full text length scrolling?(text length is less than marquee width)

Tags: php, scroll, full-text-search, marquee

I have php code like

```
echo" <marquee  width=\"100\"  behavior=\"slide\" ><font color=green>".$username."</font></marquee>";
```

and  I want the marquee stop scrolling when it shows full length of text in variable $username.Or we can say marquee direction to the right but not stop at the left edge, just want it stop at text width scrolling.
Note that, marquee's width is greater than text length in $username.

Comment: marquee O____O .. Don't Do It

Comment: You really shouldn't be using the `marquee` element. It is non-compliant HTML, and all though it works on (all?) browsers, the same can be achieved with JS.

Comment: marquee reminds me of the altavista era of the internet. RIP

Comment: have any guild with JS? Niklas.

Comment: Weird, seeing two marquee questions pop up in one day. There was a discussion about it here earlier today; some answers contained possible solutions you might want to look into: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228755/html-scrolling-text/6228780#6228780

Comment: @carbaret: Yeah, I was there too.

Comment: @carbaret @Midas its because minutes after a question is asked on SO, its at the top of google search listings.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use javascript instead. Libraries like JQuery and Motools have functions that make it easy to create an effect like the one you want.
Marquee is not a standard HTML element, so there is no guarantee that it will perform correctly unless the browser choice is controlled. Or to quote the w3 HTML wiki on marquee

> No, really. don't use it.

Comment: It's not advised by W3C because moving text is distracting.

Comment: True, it is just the quote I found at [http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/marquee]